# How to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP and multiple tasks with PendingIntents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm developing a multi room chat application for Android based on SocketIO. This is my first Android app so maybe I'm missing something silly. The structure of the app is basically an activity for the home screen and an activity that connects to the SocketIO server and offers a chat interface.

The application provides an intent filter for opening special matching links in order to launch the chat application with the "room" field already filled. When I open one of these "special links" the app is launched with a new task, so I can have 2 chat sessions running at the same time.

Intent filter code

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="mychat.example.com"
                  android:pathPrefix="/mychat/room/" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Everything is working fine apart from notifications: every notification has an associated PendingIntent for resuming the chat session if new messages arrive. For resuming I'm using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP.
Here's the code for resuming the app

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Room.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(message.toString()).setNumber(++notificationMessages);
Notification note = mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent).build();
note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, note);
```

If I use the app from the launcher everything works fine, but with the task launched from an intent-filter there's a bug with the notification. **If I receive a message on the task from the intent-filter and I tap on the notification the app from the launcher is resumed instead of the one from the intent-filter.**

Any hint?

Thanks!

Comment: post the entire manifest. You aren't generating multiple tasks even though you think you are. That's your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't know if "task" is the right name but if i keep the "home" button pressed in the list I see my application task and another task with my application opened from a link in facebook messenger (for example) with an intent filter. So I think I have multiple tasks, am I wrong? I am not generating them directly, they are generated by opening the app using the intent filter

Comment: As I wrote, please  post the rest of your manifest. Maybe that will help solve the issue.

Comment: Here you are http://pastebin.com/1Z6T2LeF (I made a pastebin as it's too long to post it here)

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to do, but please try this: add `android:taskAffinity=""` to the `<activity>` tag for the `Room` activity. Please let me know if that solves the problem or not

Comment: No, that causes the notification to launch a new task (and so a new chat session). I want to resume the last activity in the task that triggered the notification

Comment: OK. I'm still not sure that I completely understand your archtecture. However, if you are saying that you have multiple tasks, and each task  has a chat session for a specific room, and you have a Notification that should resume the correct task, this architecture won't work. In Android, if you have multiple tasks that contain the same activities, there is no way for you to tell android which of the several tasks to resume. You need to come up with a different architecture. Maybe, if you give us more details about your architecture, we can suggest an alternative that works.

Comment: Ok, so there's no way to achieve that. In the end I changed my app to let the user have only one chat session at a time. Thank you for your help

Comment: To get this question off the "unanswered" list, can you please answer your own question and accept that answer? Thanks!

Comment: Actually it's still unsolved.

Comment: See Kouchat app sourcecode on github